# It's a way to select by default N/A checkbox

Tags: 7, entities

I want that if a fields is not mandatory the N/A options on select box is ticked by default.

I have tried to tick default value N/A on the field but after the setting disappear.

I use Drupal 7.15.

Cordially

Comment: I've experienced problems with administrative forms when I'm using different administrative themes with a non-overlay.  Are you not using the overlay?  If not, try setting the N/A option with the overlay enabled.